# Is there a way to stop the blinking/blinding cursor in wxdemo code windows?

Tags: python, accessibility, text-cursor, caret

I don't know much about python, but I have instructions to create a pdf tool using wxdemo. I have a neurological issue where flashing objects often blind me, among other symptoms.

So I can't see text input and code windows with blinking cursors.

Is there a fix for this blinking/blinding cursor?

I am using MacOS so unfortunately there is no system-wide fix to stop all blinking/blinding cursors.